# Styling an icon defined with prepend-icon in Vuetify

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

Normally to style an icon in Vuetify we'll do something like

```
<v-icon large color="primary">comment</v-icon>
```

How do we get the same effect while using the `prepend-icon` prop like here

```
<v-list-group prepend-icon="comment">
```

The documentation says `prepend-icon` uses same syntax as `v-icon` but no concrete example is provided for my use case

Comment: Afaik styling them can't be done by using properties, so you must use css for styling prepend/append icons.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Target it properly and apply style.
For example in `v-list-group`:

```
.v-list__group__header__prepend-icon .v-icon {
    color: red;
}
```

But note for example `v-text-field` append icon

```
.v-input__icon--append .v-icon { 
    color: purple;
}
```

**NOTE:** If it's not working, and you are using scoped styles, see [how to resolve it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50985784/1981247).

Care not to use *only* `.v-icon` because for example you might override append icon as well, which might not be what you want.
Also, `!important` is not a good practice and we don't need to use it here.
So just rotate `.v-list__group__header__prepend-icon` class depending on component or even add your own class. Inspect element and see what the class is for prepend/append icon because it's not always same.
(if you are using scoped styles then perhaps there is no need for adding your own additional selectors for targeting the specific icons).

[Example codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OoQYap)

Note: I'm not aware of any vuetify's own classes or props for styling prepend/append icons. So if these exist or get implemented in the future, use them.

Answer (score 27):

Using a `v-icon` inside the `prependIcon` slot of the `v-list-group` template (instead of the `prepend-icon` prop) will give you all the flexibility you need:

```
<v-list-group>
  <v-icon slot="prependIcon" large color="primary">comment</v-icon>
</v-list-group>
```

There's also an `appendIcon` slot available, btw. The official [Vuetify documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list-group/#slots) mentions the available slots, but is rather silent about any details.

Comment: I cannot seem to find the documentation for this. Could you include a link to where this is written?

Comment: found it: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#icon-slots

Comment: This is the right anwer, It should be the accepted answer

Comment: Slots have been updated in 2.6.0+. Now "slot" is a deprecated syntax, and v-slot should be used. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots

Answer (score 15):

Many of the Veutify items provide slots for appending and prepending icons. And via this icons can be colored/sized as like a normal v-icon components.

```
<v-text-field>
  <template v-slot:append>        
    <v-icon color="green"> mdi-arrow-up-bold </v-icon> 
  </template>
</v-text-field>
```

*Side note:
And, as it is a slot, it's not just icons that you can append. But you can append anything for eg: A tooltip!!*

Documentation: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#icon-slots

Answer (score 0):

This will work (taken from [official documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#icon-slots)):

> Instead of using prepend / append / append-outer icons you can use
>   slots to extend input's functionality.

```
<v-list-group>
<template v-slot:prepend>
    <v-tooltip bottom>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-icon v-on="on" color="yellow">place</v-icon>
        </template>
        tooltip text
      </v-tooltip>
    </template>
</v-list-group>
```

In case of a tex field component for example, it can be useful to leave the tooltip text empty as it can clear the icon when you type in (I experienced this)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on [Annes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67429920/9659165), but I guess its important to add that in Vue 3 you can do this to create an inner append / prepend:

```
<v-text-field> 
    <template v-icon:appendInner>
        <font-awesome-icon icon='eye'>
    </template>
</v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

While working on vuetify 3, I had the same issue, to solve it I added a class to my element then I used `:deep`.

For example :

```css
<style scoped>
.item-icon :deep(.v-icon) {
    margin-right: 10px;
  } 
</style>
```