# How to change <v-text-field> icon's color?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

In my `<v-toolbar>` component, I want to set a text field search with the icon search prepended:

```
<v-text-field                                                                                                                                  
    solo-inverted                                                                                                                                                        
    prepend-icon="search"                                                                                                                                                
    label="Search"                                                                                                                                                       
    class="hidden-sm-and-down"                                                                                                                                           
    >                                                                                                                                                                    
</v-text-field>
```

This works but it gives me this result I do not like:

[image]

I do not like it because I want both the text field and icon in white color, so I added the property `background-color="white"`  to the previous code:

```
<v-text-field                                                                                                                                                          
    background-color="white"                                                                                                                                             
    solo-inverted                                                                                                                                                        
    prepend-icon="search"                                                                                                                                                
    label="Search"                                                                                                                                                       
    class="hidden-sm-and-down"                                                                                                                                           
    >                                                                                                                                                                    
</v-text-field>
```

This gives me half of what I want:

[image]

How can change the color of that icon into white?

I did some search on [Vuetify.js API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields) but could not see an appropriate option there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling an icon defined with prepend-icon in Vuetify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282241/styling-an-icon-defined-with-prepend-icon-in-vuetify)

Comment: your question help to me with following codes `filled
        light
        background-color="white"` thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override icon color by class

OR

You can use `v-text-field` class to override icon color, for example:

```
.hidden-sm-and-down .v-icon {
    color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer, I forgot dot in front of v-icon, it's a class not html tag

Comment: Please note that your answer promotes a [bad practice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) (w.r.t. `!important`) and has potential side effects. See an answer in the linked question.

Answer (score 7):

Had a similar problem. So I show as example the color-picker with vuetify

```
<v-menu
    v-model="menu"
    :close-on-content-click="false"
    transition="scale-transition"
>
    <v-text-field
       slot="activator"
       v-model="newClass.color.hex"
       label="color"
       readonly
    >
       <v-icon slot="prepend" :color="newClass.color.hex">
          format_color_fill
       </v-icon>
    </v-text-field>
    <material-picker v-model="newClass.color" />
 </v-menu>
```