# Vuetify carousel icon color

Tags: vuetify.js

Is there a way to over-ride the styling on the Vuetify `carousel` next/prev icons? I see there are fields to use custom ones, but I'd like to keep the default `$vuetify.icons.next` and just change its color.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52271983/1981247) on similar question.

Answer (score 3):

One way of changing the icons color in `Carousel` is by adding `dark` or `light` property to the `Carousel` like this. See [props in Vuetify Carousel](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/carousels)

```
<v-carousel
  light
  delimiter-icon="stop"
  prev-icon="mdi-arrow-left"
  next-icon="mdi-arrow-right"

>
```

Another way is by adding the css class:

```
.v-btn .v-btn__content .v-icon {
        color: black;
    }
```